# Keras Deep NN does not include all the the classes

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, multiclass-classification

I have made a model which has been trained to predict a number from 34-63 (no decimal numbers) In total that is 30 potential outputs.

When I run the model it complains and wants me to put in 15 in my last layer, which I have understood should be the number of outputs.

I Also get following output in the terminal after it has been trained:

```
ValueError: y_true and y_pred contain different number of classes 7, 16. Please provide the true labels explicitly through the labels argument. Classes found in y_true: [51 52 53 54 56 59 63]
```

When i then run model with:

```
prediction = model.predict(test)
print(model.predict(test))
print(np.argmax(model.predict(test), axis=-1))
```

i get:

WARNING:tensorflow:6 out of the last 19 calls to <function Model.make_predict_function..predict_function at 0x000001B8C4EB1AF0> triggered tf.function retracing. Tracing is expensive and the excessive number of tracings could be due to (1) creating @tf.function repeatedly in a loop, (2) passing tensors with different shapes, (3) passing Python objects instead of tensors. For (1), please define your @tf.function outside of the loop. For (2), @tf.function has experimental_relax_shapes=True option that relaxes argument shapes that can avoid unnecessary retracing. For (3), please refer to https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#controlling_retracing and https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function for  more details.

```
[[0.00006836 0.33038142 0.22732003 0.03764497 0.22742009 0.01213347
  0.16344884 0.00000338 0.0012028  0.00014862 0.00000717 0.00017032
  0.00000437 0.00001909 0.00002712]]
[1]
```

I am guessing that the matrix is suppose to be all the sizes but there are only 15. I Have looked in my dataset and all classes has at least 3 instances so they should be included in the training.

#UPDATE i have included the model underneath

```
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None, "display.max_columns", None)
config = ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
session = InteractiveSession(config=config)

Labeldata = ['Output_Label']

RelevantFeatures = ['column A','column B','column X']
RelevantFeaturesandlabel = ['column A','column B','column X','Output_Label']

PATH = 'Training_Data.xlsx'
PATHVa = 'Validation_Data.xlsx'

Full_Data = pd.read_excel(PATH)
ValidationFull = pd.read_excel(PATHVa)

# Which range of outputs should be included
Full_Data = Full_Data[(Full_Data['Output_Label'] >= 34) & (Full_Data['Output_Label'] <= 70)]
ValidationFull = ValidationFull[(ValidationFull['Output_Label'] >= 34) & (ValidationFull['Output_Label'] <= 70)]


FeatureDatadf = Full_Data.filter(items = RelevantFeatures, axis = 1)
Validation = ValidationFull.filter(items = RelevantFeatures, axis = 1)
ValidationLabel = ValidationFull.filter(items = Labeldata, axis = 1)
FeatureData = pd.DataFrame(StandardScaler().fit_transform(FeatureDatadf))
Validation = pd.DataFrame(StandardScaler().fit_transform(Validation))

FeatureData = FeatureData.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
FeatureData = FeatureData.to_numpy()
Validation = Validation.to_numpy()

#Standardisation
LabelData = Full_Data.filter(items = Labeldata, axis=1)
LabelData = LabelData.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
dummies = pd.get_dummies(['34','35','36','37','38','39','40','41','42','43','44','45','46','47','48','49','50','51','52','53','54','55','56','57','58','59','60','61','62','63'], prefix = 'Size')
dummies = pd.get_dummies(LabelData['Output_Label'],prefix = 'Size')
LabelData = dummies.to_numpy()



# Split the sets up
Feature_train, Feature_test, Label_train, Label_test = train_test_split(FeatureData, LabelData, test_size=0.2)

# Model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(26, activation = LeakyReLU(alpha=1), input_dim = 26,activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(1e-4),use_bias=False))#209))
model.add(Dense(26,RandomFourierFeatures(output_dim=1024, scale=10.0, kernel_initializer="gaussian"),use_bias=False))
model.add(Dense(26,RandomFourierFeatures(output_dim=1024, scale=10.0, kernel_initializer="gaussian"),use_bias=False))
model.add(Dense(26,RandomFourierFeatures(output_dim=1024, scale=10.0, kernel_initializer="gaussian"),use_bias=False))
model.add(Dense(50,RandomFourierFeatures(output_dim=1024, scale=10.0, kernel_initializer="gaussian"),use_bias=False))


model.add(Dense(26, activation = LeakyReLU(alpha=1),use_bias=False))
model.add(Dense(26,Dropout(0.4),use_bias=False))
model.add(Dense(26, activation = LeakyReLU(alpha=1),use_bias=False))
model.add(Dense(26, activation = LeakyReLU(alpha=1),use_bias=False))
model.add(Dense(26, activation = LeakyReLU(alpha=1),use_bias=False))
model.add(Dense(26,Dropout(0.4),use_bias=False))
model.add(Dense(26, activation = LeakyReLU(alpha=1),use_bias=False))
model.add(Dense(26, activation = LeakyReLU(alpha=1),use_bias=False))
model.add(Dense(26, activation = LeakyReLU(alpha=1),use_bias=False))
model.add(Dense(26,Dropout(0.4),use_bias=False))
model.add(Dense(26, activation = LeakyReLU(alpha=1),use_bias=False))
model.add(Dense(26, activation = LeakyReLU(alpha=1),use_bias=False))
model.add(Dense(26, activation = LeakyReLU(alpha=1),use_bias=False))
model.add(Dense(26,Dropout(0.4),use_bias=False))
model.add(Dense(26, activation = LeakyReLU(alpha=1),use_bias=False))
model.add(Dense(26, activation = LeakyReLU(alpha=1),use_bias=False))



model.add(Dense(26,GaussianNoise(stddev = 0.5),use_bias=False))
model.add(Dense(26,GaussianNoise(stddev = 0.5),use_bias=False))
model.add(Dense(26,GaussianNoise(stddev = 0.5),use_bias=False))
model.add(Dense(26,GaussianNoise(stddev = 0.5),use_bias=False))
model.add(Dense(26,GaussianNoise(stddev = 0.5),use_bias=False))
#model.add(Dense(25,Normalization(),use_bias=False))
model.add(Dense(26, activation = LeakyReLU(alpha=1), activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(1e-4),use_bias=False))
model.add(Dense(26, activation = LeakyReLU(alpha=1), activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(1e-4),use_bias=False))
model.add(Dense(26, activation = LeakyReLU(alpha=1), activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(1e-4),use_bias=False))
model.add(Dense(26, activation = LeakyReLU(alpha=1), activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(1e-4),use_bias=False))


model.add(Dense(15, activation = 'softmax',use_bias=False))#Output is the number of classes

#optimisation
opt = SGD(lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)

# Compile
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])

history = model.fit(Feature_train, Label_train, validation_data=(Feature_test, Label_test), epochs=500, verbose=1)

# evaluate the model
_, train_acc = model.evaluate(Feature_train, Label_train, verbose=1)
_, test_acc = model.evaluate(Feature_test, Label_test, verbose=1)
print('Train: %.3f, Test: %.3f' % (train_acc, test_acc))
# plot loss during training
pyplot.subplot(211)
pyplot.title('Loss')
pyplot.plot(history.history['loss'], label='train')
pyplot.plot(history.history['val_loss'], label='test')
pyplot.legend()
# plot accuracy during training
pyplot.subplot(212)
pyplot.title('categorical_accuracy')
pyplot.plot(history.history['categorical_accuracy'], label='train')
pyplot.plot(history.history['val_categorical_accuracy'], label='test')
pyplot.legend()
pyplot.show()


prediction = model.predict(Validation)

Predictionsdf = pd.DataFrame(prediction, columns = dummies.columns)

Predictionsdf.to_excel('Preditions.xlsx', index = False)

#Save model
model.summary()

model.save(os.path.join('.', 'Output_Label.h5'))


score = metrics.log_loss(ValidationLabel, prediction)
print("Log loss score: {}".format(score))
```

The data structure as it is now:
[image]

1. How can I fix the model error and make my network so that it includes all the classes

UPDATED
2) How can i print the prediction of the top 3 classes: their accuracy and their name?

UPDATED So i have the following code for printing the prediction and their accuracy:

```
prediction = model_Chest.predict(test)
print(model_Chest.predict(test))
y_pred = model_Chest.predict(test)
# top_k has shape (N, k)
K=18
dummies = pd.get_dummies(['44','45', '46','47', '48','49', '50','51', '52','53', '54','55', '56','57', '58','59', '60', '61'], prefix = 'Size')
top_K = np.argsort(y_pred, -1)[:, :K]
names = dummies.columns.to_numpy()[top_K]
probs = np.take_along_axis(y_pred, top_K, -1)
print(names)
print(probs)
```

It is suppose to:

- Print out the acc prediction from [44-61]
- Print the name in order from biggest to smallest
- Print out the acc prediction from Biggest to smallest

But i get:
[image]

Comment: What was the error that caused you to put only 15 classes for the final layer?

Comment: `ValueError: Shapes (None, 15) and (None, 30) are incompatible`

Comment: What are the shapes of the feature and label matrices? (i.e. `Feature_train`, `Label_train`, etc.)

Comment: Feature_train is an Array of floats: 262,26
Label_train is an Array of uint8: 328, 15

Comment: Both train arrays should have the same first dimension, so something's wrong there. Your labels should also have 30 for the second dimension because they should be a one-hot encoding of the 30 classes. So make sure all 30 classes are present in the table before using `pd.get_dummies()`.

Comment: I have fixed the first dimension as you mentioned (something was missing from the dataset) As can be seen in the new update above. But i have yet to find a way to insure that all the classes are included before the dummies. Any suggestions?

Comment: How many classes are actually present in `LabelData['Output_Label']`? Something like `LabelData['Output_Label'].describe()`.

Comment: count: 384.000000,  mean: 55.289062,  std: 3.111888, min: 51.000000,
  25%       53.000000,
  50%       55.000000,
  75%       57.000000,
  max       69.000000,
  Name: Output_Label, dtype: float64

Comment: Okay i can see now that my dataset had me confused. yes there are only 15 classes, but is it possible to make it print the prediction as the class and not the name of the order ?

Comment: What do you mean? It's currently predicting a probability distribution over classes, from which you can get the class using argmax.

Comment: When i use the argmax it does not print out the name of the class, but the position it is in the probability distribution.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67140570/keras-deep-nn-does-not-include-all-the-the-classes?noredirect=1#comment118694835_67140570), the number of classes in the dataset was only 15, hence why an output of 15 values is appropriate.

To get the top `k` class probabilities you can use `numpy.argsort` and then use the dataframe columns to get the class name:

```py
y_pred = model.predict(x)
# top_k has shape (N, k)
top_k = np.argsort(y_pred, -1)[:, :k]
names = dummies.columns.to_numpy()[top_k]
probs = np.take_along_axis(y_pred, top_k, -1)
```

`names` then contains the names of the top `k` classes for each instance in `x` and `probs` contains the corresponding probabilities.

Comment: `probs` should be the top `k` probabilities, whereas `predict()` returns all 15.